# Understanding http response

Tags: amazon-ec2

My site has just been monstered by an incontinent spiderbot. I've blocked it via htaccess, but my apache logs show a http response "403 199". 403 is fine. What's 199? 
Also why is it still using 20% of my cpu?

Answer (score 2):

- That `199` is the size of the response in bytes. Check out "Common Log Format" at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats
- *"why is it still using 20% of my cpu?"* - probably it's still a lot of requests to handle? And if you're on a t2.something EC2 instance you may have ran out of CPU credits, thus running with very limited CPU resources.
- If you know the IP / IP range of the bot you'll be better off blocking it using IP Tables as that will use a lot less CPU resources.

  ```
  ~ # iptables -I INPUT -s BOT.IP.AD.DR -j DROP
  ```

BTW *"incontinent spiderbot"* ... `ò_ô` ...?!

Hope that helps :)

Comment: To clarify slightly on the 2nd point. If you are using htaccess to block the request, apache is still receiving the request and trying to process it which will take up resources. Blocking at the device firewall level or even better on a firewall outwith the server would help resolve the issue. If the number of requests are large enough however IP tables can also become overwhelmed (if for example you are logging and blocking ip's if they try x amount of connections in a given time)

Answer (score 1):

The 403 code means 'forbidden' as you probably know. What follows the HTTP response code in your log files would depend on the LogFormat directive that's in effect for your server/vhost/site/whatever. You might want to check the Apache [custom log format stuff](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) and compare this to what's in your apache conf file.

For example, on my machine (which serves only one website) the apache conf in effect for the site, (/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf) contains this little bit:

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

That says that my access log uses the nickname `combined` which we defined in a separate/main apache conf file (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf) like so:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

The 403 in your example corresponds to the `%>s` format flag. From the docs:

```
%s - . For requests that have been internally redirected, this is the status of the original request. Use %>s for the final status.
```

That is followed by %O which is the number of bytes sent:

```
%O -  sent, including headers. May be zero in rare cases such as when a request is aborted before a response is sent. You need to enable mod_logio to use this.
```

So don't sweat the '199' that's just the number of bytes sent in your response. If your server is sending the exact same page every time, this might just be the number of chars in the HTML response.